# How to stop Wordpress Search form from searching only in current page?

Tags: search, query-string

My wordpress search form (code below) appends the query string to current page only. For example if I go to `http://Website/unknown-page` and then use the form to search for some content the query string looks like this `http://Website/unknown-page?s=Search` and only searches within the current page. It should be searching from the root like this: `http://Website/?s=Search`

How do I fix this?

```
                     <form class="form-inline" role="search">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="search">Search:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="s" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                                  </div>
                                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you omit the `action` attribute from the `form` tag, it defaults to the current URL. Give an explicit URL for the form's action to direct it to a specific URL-

```
<form class="form-inline" role="search" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
```